# Is it possible to find where a specific thrown exception could be caught in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I'm trying to trace a IO resource leak, where a connection is opened, but not necessarily closed:

```
try{ 
     ...
     urlConnection.connect();
     ...
     connectionResult.setResultInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     return connectionResult;

} catch (IOException e) {
     throw new ValidationException(e, new LocationData(submissionURL.toExternalForm(), -1, -1));
}
```

Is there a way I can find out where `ValidationException` will be caught through the call hierarchy? The manual steps are something like:

1. Do call heirarchy of containing method
2. For each caller:

   - Analyse surrounding code, finding try catch blocks
   - If exception caught, evaluate stream closing
   - If not, repeat 1.

#### Notes

- This is not reproducible; only one customer has this issue in their failover environment - the product version is 5 years old, and has never shown issues like this before.
- I can find all cases where the exception is thrown; I want to find where this particular thrown exception could be *caught* (including `catch Exception` etc)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not supported by Eclipse "out of the box".  Their might be an Eclipse plugin that supports this, but I've not heard of one.  (This is something that you rarely need to do in practice ... so there's little justification for going to the effort of implementing this.)

One alternative to code analysis is to hack the code to throw the exception under some circumstance that you can control, and then use the Java debugger to see where it actually gets caught.

Another alternative might be to hack together a custom PMD rule to identify the relevant catches.  I don't think it would be simple though ...

Comment: Yeah - not worth the effort of trying to get Jonas up and running with my 6 year old application...

Comment: plus the fact that it's not reproducible

Comment: @Stephen - I don't understand your comment about "jonas".  Do you mean JOnAS?  How is this relevant to your question?

Comment: Yes JOnAS - setting up a overly complex legacy app on unfamiliar technology with debugging etc tends to eat hours of time, where my manual inspection should be more correct and only took 10-15m. Just not worth the effort to save my brain some work, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Search->Java. In the dialog you can search for Constructors and set the Limit to References. This should give you all the places where the Exception is being thrown.

Comment: He wants the places where the exception is caught, directly or by catching superclasses of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

What about dynamic analysis?  If you can debug your program, you can set a Breakpoint Exception from the Breakpoints view.  It's the little button with an '!' and a 'J' on it, and it will break any time the exception you care about is thrown.  Then you can step to see where it is caught.

Of course it'll only find those cases that you can actual exercise by debugging.

Comment: Yes; unfortunately, my issue is not reproducible (I've added notes to the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory analyzer, such as jvisualvm/visualvm and have it log object allocations. When you expect all the resources to be closed, check the live objects and find out where they were constructed.

Comment: The problem is it's only reproducible on one customer environment (their failover system) for a product that's around 5 years old...

Answer (score 0):

Bug 296947 - [call hierarchy] Find where catch blocks are for an exception 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=296947